# TFS Team Query: get all changed work items since a given time

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Apparently it is impossible to provide the Changed Date field with a timestamp (format '2009-12-14 10:00:00') when defining a new Team Query. I get the error: "The query failed. You cannot supply a time with the date when running a query using date precision.".

Is there a workaround for this? I just want a list of work items which are changed since the last 'x' minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to write your own WIQL query: http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/01/specifying-date-and-time-in-wiql.html.

Answer (score 2):

You to enter the date in the same format as it is displayed by VSTS:  dd-MMM-YY (01-Jan-16).

Answer (score 1):

In order to filter your items in TFS by a specific date, stick to this format:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try adding query parameter `timePrecision:true`. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while trying to query for the latest updates and worked around it by doing the following

```
// defined elsewhere
private DateTime lastUpdated;


string consult = "select * from WorkItem where [Created Date] > ' "  + lastUpdated.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + 
                    "' AND [Work Item Type] = 'Test Case'";

IEnumerable<ITestCase> tcc = testManagementTeamProject.TestCases.Query(consult).Where(tp => tp.DateCreated > lastUpdated);
```

I did something very similar for retrieving test results

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of this [query constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb133075%28vs.80%29.aspx) lets you define the precision:

> *dayPrecision*
>
> When TRUE, indicates that a DateTime should resolve to an entire day. Often, it is TRUE to avoid being more precise about a specific time.